# Dynamically accessing a button when I know the button number

Tags: java, swing

Nine `JButtons` are declared as :

```
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
```

I could have had a button array but it doesn't suit the application.During the program run I want to dynamically access a button when I know the button number.Like at some instance I want for button number `5`, `setText("X")`. Is there any way I can do that ? A `JButton` array would have solved the problem very easily by just doing :

```
buttonArray[5].setText("X")
```

but as I told, it overall doesn't suit the application.

Accessing a button by its number is one thing. If there is any other way to do this,please mention.

Comment: Not sure why you can't use an array, but if these are class fields you can use reflection.

Comment: There is a really nasty, hacky method, which I'm reluctant to share as it's really a demonstration of bad design.  It would be better to use an array or `List` (you could keep the current list of variables and still add them to another array/`List`)

Comment: Under what conceivable circumstances is 9 unique variables better than an array?

Comment: @John3136 I already know array/list is a much better option.But the situation is such,I cannot go back and make an array for some 35 buttons. I was given the code and asked to extend its functionality.I guess if I make an array,I will break the code

Comment: @SuhailGupta: given the probable quality of the code, my guess is that everyone will be better off if you get rid of it and start over. It's so much easier and more time effective to create code right the first time than trying to debug and hack your way through rough code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree with you and I already acknowledge that.But I have to.

Comment: Then best of luck with that code base.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and write Switch statement as many as number of Jbuttons. Pass the number to the function and return the appropriate Nth number of Jbutton object. This is the only possible way in all given circumstances. There is no other way in java. There is something called class.forname to create class out of String but that creates new class which is of no use to you.

Comment: @suhail, What did you implement in the end ?